# Using a single QSqlDatabase connection in multiple qt threads

Tags: multithreading, qt, sqlite, qtsql

I have a multi threaded Qt application which has multiple threads accessing a single database. Am I required create separate QSqlDatabase connections for performing SELECT / INSERT / UPDATE in each thread?

From Qt documentation, I am unable to understand if the following guideline is discouraging the above approach I suggested:

> "A connection can only be used from within the thread that created it.
>   Moving connections between threads or creating queries from a
>   different thread is not supported."

I have practically tried using the same connection in my multiple QThreads and all works fine practically but wanted to understand if its the correct thing to do.

> FYI, I am using sqlite3 from within Qt (using Qtsql API) which I understand supports serialized mode by
>   default: https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

The reason I want to use the same connection name in multiple threads is because when I tried using different connections to the same database on multiple threads and performed SELECT / INSERT  / UPDATE, I got `database locked` issue quite frequently. However, on using the same connection in multiple threads, this issue got eliminated completely.

Kindly guide on the same.

Regards,

Saurabh Gandhi

Comment: maybe create a wrapper class that has some slots to insert/update/delete and have it in its own thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is not merely discouraging it, it flatly states that you must not do it (emphasis mine):

> A connection **can only be used from within the thread that created it**.

So, no, **you can't use one connection from multiple threads**. It might happen to work, but it's not guaranteed to work, and you're invoking what amounts to undefined behavior. It's not guaranteed to crash either, mind you.

You need to either:

1. Serialize the access to the database on your end, or
2. Change the connection parameters so that locks don't reject a query but block until the database becomes available. I'm not quite sure what the `database locked` "issue" is: you should never see that error code (I presume it is SQLITE_LOCKED) if you actually use multiple connections. Sqlite 3 can be easily used from multiple threads, it shouldn't require any effort on your end other than enabling multithreading and using separate connections.